# Facebook like button display under content- squarespace

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, rendering, squarespace

Im trying to add a facebook like button to my website, however when you click the like button, the share bubble appears under the content.

Im using facebook´s HTML5 button on squarespace

You can see the problem here, at the bottom of the page

http://mindarin.com/

The share bubble appears under the logo, it happens everywhere though, if I place the button where I want to ( top of page ) the bubble appears behind the main image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the share tooltip by adding `overflow:hidden;height: 21px;` to fb-like widget css.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;height: 21px;" class="fb-like" [...] />
```

Comment: I dont really want to hide it, since the sharing function is what im looking for. Likes are not longer shared in other people timeline.